# context menu actionUrl in sharepoint 2013 - call jsp

Tags: jsp, contextmenu, sharepoint-2013

i have a solution which applies a sharepoint context menu for document library list items that works perfectly in SP2010, but does not run the actionUrl in SP2013 (the context menu appears correctly in the site lists).

i have validated the context menu definition by calling a javascript alert from the actionUrl, and this works, so i don't understand why the jsp i'm trying to call no longer gets fired.
i've also checked that the corresponding jsp is deployed to the 15 hive in SP2013 - (could there be a missing reference to tell the solution where the jsp is deployed?)

here is the context menu definition;

```
<CustomAction Id="UserInterfaceLightUp.DocLibNewToolbar"
                            Description="Opens the document in Oracle AutoVue for viewing, applying markup and collaborating."
                            RegistrationType="ContentType"
                            RegistrationId="0x0101"
                            Rights="ManagePermissions"
                            Location="EditControlBlock"
                            Sequence="1"
                            Title="View in AutoVue"
                            FeatureId="100ecce9-2c74-4c3f-b1e9-0c54ade35490">

<UrlAction Url="javascript: showLaunchAutoVueDialog('{ItemUrl}', null, '{SiteUrl}');" />

</CustomAction>
```

my questions;
firstly is there something blatantly wrong with the jsp function call in the actionUrl definition above?
if not, is there something different i need to do to register/reference the jsp for use in the 2013 solution..

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the call in an anonymous function, for example:

```
<UrlAction Url="javascript: (function() { showLaunchAutoVueDialog('{ItemUrl}', null, '{SiteUrl}'); })();" />
```

That should do it.

Comment: Hi there Steve, thanks for the reply, but this still isn't firing the JSP...?  How and where should the script page be referenced? Thanks, Drew